# Image Slider not sliding images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the example found on popular web learning site w3schools for the [Image Slider](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

I've placed the HTML in the index.html file, the CSS in the stylesheet.css file, the JavaScript in the javascript.js file,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  // Next/previous controls
  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }
  // Thumbnail image controls
  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }
  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}
/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4;
  } 
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4;
  } 
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.sm.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.sm.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>
<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It simply does not slide the images.

I've checked the jQuery and used multiple types to no avail.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Is the pics folder placed at same location as the index.html file? Press F12 in your browser and check if there is any exception in console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First try to keep all CSS and JS in the HTML file and see if that works. If it works then place them into separate files. You can also try to put your JS file entry in the body tag of your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the function definitions outside the `$(document).ready()`
When declaring functions or variables inside of the `$(document).ready()` they become  inaccessible to the  `onclick()` binding in the document.

```js
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Slide Image Webpage</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<!--        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="pics/img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="pics/img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="pics/img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked a treat. I think that w3schools should mention what you've stated in there tutorial on this since the best way to handle HTML, CSS and javascript is to use three separate files.

Comment: Just to clarify the above solution. `$(document).ready()` should only contain the call to the functions. All global variables and functions **MUST** be outside  `$(document).ready()`